# how to include YoutubePlaylist into html?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I have this code in my html file and it is not working, is there any mistake?

```
<iframe class="video" src="
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLugGnSaLgr_1zb5n91s6okPtwm0MfgFD1?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=0&loop=0&mute=1&cc_lang_pref=en&cc_load_policy=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Not working means what output you are getting?

Comment: Hi Bejgam, simply, everything is black but it is maybe because of CSS, but video playlist is not there in any case.  I tried to click on the whole monitor to activate playlist, no success. I will try later to remove css, in this moment I can't use putty/ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLugGnSaLgr_1zb5n91s6okPtwm0MfgFD1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```